# Cannot return after sending response

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, http

My express app is getting crashed after sending a response to the client. It seems the code is still getting executed even after returning.
Please check out the code snippet below.

```
const EditUser = async (req, res) => {
    let result = validateUser(req.body);
    if(result.error) return res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);

    let data = req.body;

    let resp = connection.query(`select * from users where id = ${req.params.id}`, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send('Server side error');
        if(rows.length === 0) return res.status(404).send('User not found');
    })

    // code gets executed here.
    // further logic goes here.
}
```

Please let me know if there is any issue with this code. (PS., I am not allowed to use a User model here.)

Many thanks!

Comment: can you share the error message?

Comment: Sure, this is the error message : 
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: you are getting this error because your function may have returned response more than once.

Comment: instead of callback you can use await in connection.query to simplify the process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move ALL your logic inside the callback function, if you want a "real" asynchronous behaviour.

```js
const EditUser = async (req, res) => {
    let result = validateUser(req.body);
    if(result.error) return res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);

    let data = req.body;

    let resp = connection.query(`select * from users where id = ${req.params.id}`, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send('Server side error');
        if(rows.length === 0) return res.status(404).send('User not found');

        // code gets executed here.
        // further logic goes here.
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your function is returning the response twice. You can use ***if/else*** or ***callback*** statement to handle this.

Using *if-else*

```
const EditUser = async (req, res) => {
    let result = validateUser(req.body);
    if(result.error){ 
       return res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);
    }else {
    let data = req.body;
    let resp = await connection.query(`select * from users where id = ${req.params.id}`)
      // TODO
    }
}
```

using *callback*

```
const EditUser = async (req, res) => {
    let result = validateUser(req.body);
    if(result.error) return res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);

    let data = req.body;

    let resp = connection.query(`select * from users where id = ${req.params.id}`, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send('Server side error');
        if(rows.length === 0) return res.status(404).send('User not found');

        // code gets executed here.
        // further logic goes here.
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await`, as your function is already using `async` so you can implement this code like:

```
const EditUser = async (req, res) => {
    let result = validateUser(req.body);
    if(result.error) return res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);

    let data = req.body;

    let resp = await connection.query(`select * from users where id = ${req.params.id}`);
    if(!resp) return res.status(500).send('Server side error');
    if(resp.length === 0) return res.status(404).send('User not found');

    // code gets executed here.
    // further logic goes here.
}
```

I do not know the exact response structure, but you can take reference from this and customise your function according to your needs.